# Check if GZIP file exists in Python

Tags: python, gzip

I would like to check for the existence of a .gz file on my linux machine while running Python. If I do this for a text file, the following code works:

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile('bob.asc')
```

However, if bob.asc is in gzip format (bob.asc.gz), Python does not recognize it. Ideally, I would like to use os.path.isfile or something very concise (without writing new functions). Is it possible to make the file recognizable either in Python or by changing something in my system configuration?

Unfortunately I can't change the data format or the file names as they are being given to me in batch by a corporation.

Comment: because bob.asc.gz is not bob.asc. These are different files. you need to test them individually.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear: os.path.isfile('bob.asc') works if bob.asc is in the directory, but os.path.isfile('bob.asc.gz') does not work even if bob.asc.gz is in the directory.

Comment: `os.path.isfile` certainly *does* work on files like `bob.asc.gz`.  Can you post a complete example showing exactly what is not working for you (e.g. the output of `ls` followed by the call to `os.path.isfile` and its output)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't; they are completely different files. You need to test it separately:

```
os.path.isfile('bob.asc.gz')
```

This would return `True` if that exact file was present in the current working directory.

Although a workaround could be:

```
from os import listdir, getcwd
from os.path import splitext, basename

any(splitext(basename(f))[0] == 'bob.asc' for f in listdir(getcwd()))
```

Comment: So, my first question wasn't very clear - the first command that you wrote above is not working for me even when bob.asc.gz is present in the directory. That is, for some reason Python will not treat files with extension .gz as a file.

Answer (score 1):

After fooling around for a bit, the most concise way I could get the job done was

```
subprocess.call(['ls','bob.asc.gz']) == 0
```

which returns True if the file exists in the directory. This is the behavior I would expect from

```
os.path.isfile('bob.asc.gz')
```

but for some reason Python won't accept files with extension .gz as files when passed to os.path.isfile.

I don't feel like my solution is very elegant, but it is concise. If someone has a more elegant solution, I'd love to see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test each file. For example :

```
if any(map(os.path.isfile, ['bob.asc', 'bob.asc.gz'])):
    print 'yay'
```

Comment: I think you mean `any(map(os.path.isfile, ['bob.asc', 'bob.asc.gz'])):`. `any` only takes one argument, so this will throw a `TypeError` in its current state.